# Was Suspiria (1977) shot in 3D or was it an after the fact conversion?

Tags: 3d, suspiria-1977

I've recently stumbled across an [anaglyph 3D version](https://archive.org/details/Suspiria.19773D) of the 1977 original [SUSPIRIA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspiria). I'm a long-time fan and I'd never heard of a 3D version. Is this a recent conversion?

Comment: Are you referring to this https://www.amazon.com/Suspiria-Real-3-D-Side-Side/dp/B007GFAX9K
It's Side by Side 3D, literally two images running side by side. It requires active 3D glasses that have electronic shutters that alternately open and close to produce the 3D effect.

Comment: I am referring to an anaglyph (red and blue old-style glasses) version. [Found here](https://archive.org/details/Suspiria.19773D).

Comment: Looking at the site I'd say that Suspiria and the other films this person posted are all done by them using readily available software.  I can't find any evidence that Suspiria was anything other than a 2D movie The uploader also has the Evil Dead trilogy in 3D and none of those were filmed that way. Mostly it looks like copyright violation.